# Symbol lookup error when installing QGIS after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gdal, qgis, ubuntu-22.04

I had QGIS working on Ubuntu 21.10 but when I upgraded to 22.04 something happened and it was no longer there, so I proceeded to install it once again ([instructions](https://qgis.org/es/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu)), but when I run `qgis` i get:

```bash
/usr/bin/qgis.bin: symbol lookup error: /lib/libgdal.so.28: undefined symbol: _ZN6libdap5ErrorD1Ev
```

I'm not familiar with gdal, so got almost no clue on how to get QGIS working again (I've tried to uninstall it and install it again but it's always the same).
Not sure if it helps but running `gdalinfo --version` I get:

```bash
GDAL 3.4.1, released 2021/12/27
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest installing miniconda using https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html. Use the instructions to create a new python environment and activate it. Then install QGIS from conda using

```
conda install -c conda-forge qgis
```